# Is ASP.NET Core 5.0 conventional routing order dependent or not?

Tags: asp.net-core

In the long documentation page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0) I see information **that seems a bit contradictory** to me:

> **Conventional routing is order-dependent.**
> In general, routes with areas should be placed earlier as they're more
> specific than routes without an area. Dedicated conventional routes
> with **catch-all route parameters like {*article} can make a route too
> greedy**, meaning that **it matches URLs that you intended to be
> matched by other routes**. **Put the greedy routes later** in the
> route table **to prevent greedy matches**.

So that seems to suggest clearly that order is important and if you put a catch-all template first, it will match all.

Then we continue to [the URL matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#:%7E:text=the%20routing%20implementation%20does%20not%20guarantee%20a%20processing%20order%20for%20matching%20endpoints.%20all%20possible%20matches%20are%20processed%20at%20once.%20the%20url%20matching%20phases%20occur%20in%20the%20following%20order.%20asp.net%20core%3A) section:

> The routing implementation **does not guarantee a processing order for matching endpoints**. All **possible matches are processed at once**. The URL matching phases occur in the following order. ASP.NET Core:
>
> - Processes the URL path against the set of endpoints and their route
>   templates, **collecting all of the matches**.
> - Takes the preceding list and removes matches that fail with route constraints applied.
> - Takes the preceding list and removes matches that fail the set of MatcherPolicy instances.
> - **Uses the EndpointSelector to make a final decision from the preceding list**.
>
> The list of endpoints is prioritized according to:
>
> - The RouteEndpoint.Order
> - **The route template precedence**
>
> All matching endpoints are processed in each phase until the EndpointSelector is
> reached. The EndpointSelector is the final phase. **It chooses the
> highest priority endpoint from the matches as the best match**. If there
> are other matches with the same priority as the best match, an
> ambiguous match exception is thrown.

And a bit further below we see [the precedence mechanism explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#:%7E:text=the%20routing%20implementation%20does%20not%20guarantee%20a%20processing%20order%20for%20matching%20endpoints.%20all%20possible%20matches%20are%20processed%20at%20once.%20the%20url%20matching%20phases%20occur%20in%20the%20following%20order.%20asp.net%20core%3A)

> Route template precedence is a system that assigns each route template a **value based on how specific it is**. Route template precedence:
>
> **Avoids the need to adjust the order of endpoints** in common cases.
> Attempts to **match the common-sense expectations** of routing behavior.
> For example, consider templates /Products/List and /Products/{id}. It
> would be reasonable to assume that /Products/List is a better match
> than /Products/{id} for the URL path /Products/List. This works
> because the literal segment /List is considered to have better
> precedence than the parameter segment /{id}.
>
> The details of how precedence works are coupled to how route templates
> are defined:
>
> - Templates with more segments are considered more specific.
> - A segment with literal text is considered more specific than a parameter
>   segment.
> - A parameter segment with a constraint is considered more specific than one without.
> - A complex segment is considered as specific as a parameter segment with a constraint.
> - **Catch-all parameters are the least specific**.
>
> See catch-all in the Route template reference for important information on catch-all routes.

So, to me **it seems like precedence is more important than the order** (perhaps the order matters only when two route templates have the same precedence score?)

*My quick tests seemed to prove that point, but perhaps there's something wrong about my understanding.* Or perhaps, the [Conventional routing order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-5.0#conventional-routing-order) should be updated to reflect the current behavior.

Comment: You are right, precedence trumps order, and order is used to disambiguate routes that have the same precedence.

Comment: @davidfowl - thanks, man. Post this as an answer and I will accept :)